# Using an inputbox after a vbYes vbNo msgbox, and continue on

Tags: vba, ms-access, inputbox, msgbox

I  have a `vbYes`/`vbNo` `MsgBox` partway into my database, but either answer I would like to continue on with further inputbox prompts. However, it is giving me the following error:

> Block if without End if

Any ideas how to keep this project moving?

```
Answer1 = MsgBox("Will you be using any compensatory time?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes
If Answer1 = vbYes Then
CompTimeInfo = InputBox("You will need to calculate which days, and how many total hours of comp time you will use. Your comp time should be used up front, as in, if your orders begin on the 1st, you should use them on the next working day straight through. The next prompts will ask for this information. Please initial in the below box.", "AUS Date Initials")
If Answer1 = vbNo Then
AUSDateWithoutComp = InputBox("Please initial here, indicating that you will not be using comp time. This signifies that your AUS start date aligns with your orders start date.", "AUS Start date - No Comp Time")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have put the InputBox on a new line after `If Answer1=vbYes Then`, Access is expecting an `End If` to close that block of code.

However, because of the way that you are initializing `Answer1` by comparing the result of the `MsgBox` to vbYes, `Answer1` will be either `True` (if the user clicked "Yes") or `False`.

Your code can be modified to look like:

```
If vbYes=MsgBox("Will you be using any compensatory time?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) Then
    CompTimeInfo = InputBox("You will need to calculate which days, and how many total hours of comp time you will use. Your comp time should be used up front, as in, if your orders begin on the 1st, you should use them on the next working day straight through. The next prompts will ask for this information. Please initial in the below box.", "AUS Date Initials")
Else
    AUSDateWithoutComp = InputBox("Please initial here, indicating that you will not be using comp time. This signifies that your AUS start date aligns with your orders start date.", "AUS Start date - No Comp Time")
End If
```

Note that I've put `vbYes` on the left side of the equality check - this makes it easier to read when there is a lot of text without having to scroll all of the way to the right.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I assume the 'End If' statement closing out that function above means regardless of the solution of the two inputs now, I can continue on with another inputbox function and the program will continue to run.

Comment: Correct - you have now dealt with the Yes/No outcomes of the first `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises because each of your `If` statements will need a corresponding `End If` terminator. The general syntax for an `If` statement in VB is either:

```
If <test-expression> Then
    <then-expression1>
    ...
    <then-expressionN>
End If
```

Or with an `Else` argument:

```
If <test-expression> Then
    <then-expression1>
    ...
    <then-expressionN>
Else
    <else-expression1>
    ...
    <else-expressionN>
End If
```

Hence, to be syntactically correct, your code should become:

```
Answer1 = MsgBox("Will you be using any compensatory time?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes
If Answer1 = vbYes Then
    CompTimeInfo = InputBox("You will need to calculate which days, and how many total hours of comp time you will use. Your comp time should be used up front, as in, if your orders begin on the 1st, you should use them on the next working day straight through. The next prompts will ask for this information. Please initial in the below box.", "AUS Date Initials")
End If
If Answer1 = vbNo Then
    AUSDateWithoutComp = InputBox("Please initial here, indicating that you will not be using comp time. This signifies that your AUS start date aligns with your orders start date.", "AUS Start date - No Comp Time")
End if
```

However, note that your `then` expression will *never* be evaluated, as `Answer1` will contain a boolean value (true/false) - the result of comparing the value returned by `MsgBox` with `vbYes`.

I would therefore suggest writing your code as:

```
If MsgBox("Will you be using any compensatory time?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
    CompTimeInfo = InputBox("You will need to calculate which days, and how many total hours of comp time you will use. Your comp time should be used up front, as in, if your orders begin on the 1st, you should use them on the next working day straight through. The next prompts will ask for this information. Please initial in the below box.", "AUS Date Initials")
Else
    AUSDateWithoutComp = InputBox("Please initial here, indicating that you will not be using comp time. This signifies that your AUS start date aligns with your orders start date.", "AUS Start date - No Comp Time")
End If
```